# Automount windows network share 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, mount, fstab, automount

Since updating from 16.x to 18.04 my windows network share doesn't automount.

My /etc/fstab started like this, and worked fine in 16.x

```
//SISKO/usb_storage /media/plex cifs guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

Then I added and it wouldn't automount

```
//SISKO/usb_storage /media/plex cifs vers=1.0,sec=ntlm,guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

Then I added this, and still won't automount.

```
//SISKO/usb_storage /media/plex cifs vers=1.0,sec=ntlm,guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,_netdev,s-systemd.after=network-online.target 0 0
```

I can manually mount using, but want it to auto mount when I turn on the machine.

```
sudo mount -t cifs //SISKO/usb_storage /media/plex -o rw
```

Please help!